# "The method from ... is never used locally" on a public method inside an anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I'm implementing the `iterable` interface and returning the iterator using anonymous class.

The problem is I can't use my custom `add` from the anonymous class in the main method.

I can't call the add method in the `main` method.
Eclipse complains that it's not defined.

What is the problem?

*I'll spare from you the outer class and just show you the method iterator*:

```
@Override
public Iterator<Symbol> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<Symbol>() {
        int i = 0; //Remove i and it works. WHY?!!

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return i < symArr.length && symArr[i] != null;
        }

        public Symbol next() {
            if (hasNext()) {
                return symArr[i++];
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void add(Symbol addMe) {
            if (i < symArr.length) {
                symArr[i] = addMe;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

My `main` method inside the outer class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SymbolTable st = new SymbolTable(22);
    Iterator<Symbol> it = st.iterator();
    it.next();
    it.add(new Symbol("2", 2)); //Have problem here. 
    //Problem disappears when I completely remove i variable in the iterator method.

}
```

The whole code:

```
package tirgul_iteratorsExceptions;

import java.util.Iterator;

public class SymbolTable implements Iterable<Symbol> {

    Symbol[] symArr;

    public SymbolTable(int size) {
        symArr = new Symbol[size];
    }

    public SymbolTable(SymbolTable st, boolean isDeep) {
        symArr = new Symbol[st.symArr.length];
        if (isDeep) {
            for (int i = 0; i < st.symArr.length; i++) {
                symArr[i] = new Symbol(st.symArr[i].name, st.symArr[i].value);
            }
        }
        // Shallow copy
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < st.symArr.length; i++) {
                symArr[i] = st.symArr[i];
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Symbol> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Symbol>() {
            int i = 0;

            public boolean hasNext() {
                return i < symArr.length && symArr[i] != null;
            }

            public Symbol next() {
                if (hasNext()) {
                    return symArr[i++];
                }
                return null;
            }

            public void add(Symbol addMe) {
                if (i < symArr.length) {
                    symArr[i] = addMe;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SymbolTable st = new SymbolTable(22);
        Iterator<Symbol> it = st.iterator();
        it.next();
        it.add(new Symbol("2", 2));

    }

}
```

Comment: `I'll spare from you the outer class and just show you the method iterator:` Maybe you should, given that one of the reasons removing the field doesn't give you an error is that there is another variable `i` in scope.

Comment: @biziclop there isn't but Im adding the whole code

Comment: How do you think you'd be able to invoke that public method? You can only call methods on the super type; if it's not used inside the class, it's redundant.

Comment: it.add(new Symbol("2", 2)); why not?

Comment: `it.add` requires an `add` method on an `Iterator`, since `it` is a reference of type `Iterator`, not of your anonymous class.

Comment: You need to declare your special iterator in an inner class else the compiler can't know about your public "add" method... It's not specified anywhere in the ''Iterator'' interface.

Comment: so why here the same approch works (the remove method)?  http://pastebin.com/AhrRexPS

Comment: That's not the same. `add` is being called on a reference to `TwoWayList`, not an anonymous class.

Comment: @TheLogicGuy There is no `add()` method on the anonymous `Iterator` here, only `hasNext()`, `next()` and `remove()`, all of them defined by the `Iterator` interface.

Comment: @biziclop so if I want to use custom methods I need to declare a class the "full" way?

Comment: What's specific in your code is this new "add" method which is not in the Iterator interface. As the iterator() method returns an Iterator<> object you need to stick to this interface or to declare a new Class with your method inside ;)

Comment: And for the **record**: when I remove that declaration of "i" ... I get compile errors.

Comment: @TheLogicGuy yes. What you have now is not much different to having a method with return type `Object`, where the actual return value is a `String`: you can't invoke `String` methods on that return value, because the compiler can't guarantee that it is a `String` value.

Comment: Thank you guys! You helped me a lot and so quickly.

Comment: The contract of `Iterator#next` specifies: *"Throws: NoSuchElementException - if the iteration has no more elements"* instead of returning `null`.